# Converting raster from WGS_1984_plate_carree to WGS_1984 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84

I am a beginner using ArcGIS and I  downloaded a TIFF which is in WGS_1984_plate_carree coordinate system. This image covers all the world and in this coordinate system the extent goes from -180 (left) to 180 (right) and from -90 (bottom) to 90 (top). I need to convert it to WGS_1984 without changing its extent but when i try to convert it, using the project raster tool, i get this extent:

Top      0,000808483755708

Left     -0,00161696751142

Right    0,00161696751142

Bottom   -0,000808483755708

I know that plate carree is a projection while WGS_1984 is a geographic coordinate system but i don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: It's not clear that you need to change anything. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact steps you are taking which results in data corruption.

Comment: The raster is already in latitude-longitude. Redefine the coordinate system as wgs 1984 (wkid 4326). Do not reproject it.